# json date conversion shows different in EST and PST

Tags: javascript, json

I m using the javascript function to convert the date `{date =\/Date(1293034567877)\/}`:

```
  function getDateFromJSON(date) {
            var newdate = new Date(parseInt(date.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
        retdate = (newdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + newdate.getDate() + "/" + newdate.getFullYear();
            var retdate;
```

Ex: If the date received is `7/22/2008 12:00:00 PM` it shows correctly in `PST` and `EST` but the date received is `7/22/2008 12:00:00 AM` then it shows as `7/21/2008` for the `PST` Users.

I Just need to show date part any suggestion what i m doing wrong

Comment: Assuming you are working in the browser, I can't recommend moment.js enough. It handles a ton of the nitty-gritty Date parsing, particularly cross-browser inconsistencies.

Comment: I m trying to get the date from my Json. teh datetime is in utc and if i chnage time zope to ESt it shows correctly on the browszer btu if i change it to PST then the day part show a day earlier... im saving the dates in UTC time set to 12:00AM. i cant figure why it is show a day prior.

Comment: here we are interested in date only not the time so it should alwasy show the correct date irrespective of time it saved. im parsing it in Javascript

Comment: PST did not reach the next day yet.

Comment: `.getUTCDate()` will get you `22` for `1216684800000` which is `Tue, 22 Jul 2008 00:00:00 GMT`

Comment: yes i tried using UTC date but i m not if this doesn't put me in any trouble??

Comment: if PST did not reach next day then it should show teh same for both PST and ESt,the date is saved at with mid n8, what ever day im select in PST or EST it should have teh date and the 12 AM time for that day. but if time part is saved at noon it shows correctly for bothpST and EST.

Comment: What is the milliseconds since epoch that you are using? EST is GMT-5 so the date will still be 21 if using `1216684800000`.

Comment: not sure of milli seconds but the time part is either 12:00:00 AM or 12:00:00 PM.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UTC date functions to get no time zone changes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

`.getUTCDate()` will get you `22` for `1216684800000` which is `Tue, 22 Jul 2008 00:00:00 GMT`

If you just need the current timezone date then use `.getDate()`.

You indicate this date is not "correct" but you need to consider the date is not necessarily the same for all time zones. Make sure your stored Midnight date is at UTC or GMT0. Since EST (GMT -5) and PST (GMT -8) follow GMT0 midnight, those time zones have not advanced their date yet.

Setting my machine to EST and using `1216684800000` I get `21` for the date.

```
var d = new Date(1216684800000);
d.getDate();     // 21
d.getUTCDate();  // 22
d.toUTCString(); // Tue, 22 Jul 2008 00:00:00 GMT
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasenhk/N2Cx3/1/)